# Content not getting displayed in FlexboxLayout

Tags: android, android-flexboxlayout

I'm using below xml code to display textviews automatically to next line when there is no space in a row, but nothing is getting displayed in output.

Can anyone help in this.

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="100" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="200" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="300" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="400" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:text="500" />
</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

Comment: which version of FlexboxLayout are you using ?could you put whole your codes here?

Comment: Hi @alisamawi, I'm using     implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

try to using  'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0' if you haven't migrated to AndroidX. check it and notice me the result.